# Find the basis of this bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A$ be the matrix of a bilinear form in a certain basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, where $A$ is:

$$
A=
\left[
\matrix
{
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1    
}
\right]
$$

I've diagonalized it, and the resulting diagonal matrix is $D=diag(1,-1,-2)$, and the change of basis matrix is:

$$
P=
\left[
\matrix
{
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 1    
}
\right]
$$

So, its verified that $D=PAP^t$. However, I'm not sure how to find in which base this happens, in terms of the vectors of the old base, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you found that $P$. In any case it seems you got the transposition on the wrong side: base change of bilinear forms has the transpose of the change of basis matrix (or of its inverse, depending on the direction) on the **left**. It is therefore the *rows* of you $P$ (interpreted on the old basis) that give an orthogonal basis for the bilinear form associated to your matrix$~A$.

Comment: Oh, that's because I diagonalized it by elementary operations, and registered the ones on the rows in $P$. That's why I put the resulting matrix before, and its transpose after. However, its good to know that what I had to do is just take the rows (or columns), thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "diagonalized it by elementary operations". That is **not a valid technique** to diagonalise, whatever it may amount to, so you were very lucky to be able to diagonalize in the first place here. To see that it cannot be a valid technique, consider that symmetric matrices with integer entries are only ensured to be diagonalisable _over the real numbers_, not over the rational numbers. So diagonalising such a matrix may require irrational coefficients (not in the example of the question though), and elementary operations will never introduce irrational numbers.

Comment: I guess I wasn't mentioned that it has to be an Euclidean domain, in which case, it is possible, here's a proof: https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/every-square-matrix-over-a-euclidean-domain-can-be-diagonalized-by-elementary-row-and-column-operations/ Which is not quite the one I was shown in class, but close enough. What we do is basically do elementary operations on both the rows and the columns (the same ones, of course), but register only the rows/columns ones in a matrix.

Comment: If you want to go that way, you need to work over the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[X]$, and operate not on $A$ but on $XI-A$ (the matrix whose determinant is the characteristic polynomial). The resulting form (which is diagonal but not similar to the original matrix) gives you the Rational Canoncial Form, not a basis for diagonalisation. I really don't think this is what you did. The fact remains that a basis for diagonalisation of a symmetric matrix with integer coefficients requires non rational coefficients in general.